# How to use Infopath to Create a Custom Content Type for a List?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type

Salvete!  I want to use InfoPath to create a Content Type for a List.  I know how to create a site-content type using infopath, but that generates an form that you have to save in a library.  I want my infopath form to be inside a list's "edit mode" just like a list content type.

Is there a way to convert an infopath-built content type to have the parent of "item" instead of "form"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I deleted my initial answer.

How you want to do it is impossible. You probably shouldn't dwell on trying to do it with sharepoint list at all.

Infopath "Sharepoint List Form", in contrast to other types of templates (for ex., published to form/doc libraries, is hard-linked to its (BTW, one only and the same) sharepoint entity = sharepoint list.

You cannot separate (or change to other list) creation/updating of Sharepoint List Form once you started it except unlinking the form from its sharepoint list.
And there are very specific and restricted ways of linking/creating this form like:

- pressing "Customize Form" button on ribbon in browser having navigated to a sharepoint list
- pressing "Sharepoint List" in Infopath Designer (File > New)
- in Sharepoint Designer 2010, navigate to sharepoint list and press Design Forms in Infopath > Item on ribbon

Comment: I don't really want to create a site-content-type.  I want to create a content-type that I can use in a list, except I want it done with infopath.  I've already created the infopath content-type, but it never shows in the possible conent-types I can use in a list.  I suppose that isn't possible?  (I'm sorry, this is all very confusing!  Y'all are the only folks I have to talk to!)

Comment: I changed my answer. It is a little bit difficult to find correct words that would not inadvertently be understood in the unwarranted way

Comment: Okay, I'll mark this and abandon the idea of trying to get InfoPath to create a content type for a list.  With what research I have done, and your advice, I think you are right.

Comment: The sense of content type is in its reuse. Now, Infopath Sharepoint List Form cannot OOTB be reused, changed for another list (once it is linked), used for more than one list, etc. And, it is a little bit difficult to formulate correctly, its creation/updating/changing is inseparably linked from the start to used/linked sharepoint list. You create/change/edit Sharepoint List Form and/or list in hard linked relationship only. Thanks for marking